# Recommended book on random processes to understand new functionality in Mathematica 9?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, reference-request

I am interested in exploring the [new functionality on random processes](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/random-processes/) available in *Mathematica* 9, but I am not familiar with all of the underlying mathematics.

Could you recommend a book that provides a foundation on these topics?

I am thinking about a book that favors intuition and breadth over proofs.  I have an engineering background (and know probability and statistics decently well) and would like to rapidly take advantage of these functions.  I am interested in both modeling and estimation issues.

Comment: You can have a look at books on quantitative finance by Wilmott.

Comment: This one http://www.amazon.com/Methods-Finance-Insurance-Financial-Mathematics/dp/1420076183 and this one http://www.amazon.com/Monte-Carlo-Methods-Finance-Jaeckel/dp/047149741X are nice introductions.

Comment: Also: http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Financial-Mathematics-using-MATHEMATICA®/dp/0817641971/

Comment: if you prefer a more natural science-oriented approach,  [this](http://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Methods-Handbook-Sciences-Synergetics/dp/3642089623/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1356527620&sr=1-1&keywords=gardiner+stochastic) might be interesting. My personal favourite would be [van Kampen's book](http://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Processes-Chemistry-North-Holland-Personal/dp/0444529659/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1356527610&sr=1-1&keywords=van+kampen) but that is less formal (and more opinionated). In any case, both are less formal than is usual in other disciplines.

Comment: For a really unique approach to stochastics and probability, try: http://www.bergner.se/DMP/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Introduction to Probability Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123756863) by Ross gives good description of stochastic processes. 
[Applied Intertemporal Optimization](http://ideas.repec.org/b/gla/glabks/econ1.html) by Walde also has easy to follow structure on stochastic models in both discrete and continuous time and it is free to download pdf.

Comment: Ah good, someone remembered Ross. I wanted to add it, but my books are packed and I could not remember his name. +1